# Adding DEFINE_WAIT fails to compile in linux module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, synchronization, linux-device-driver

I added a wait queue entry by calling DEFINE_WAIT and the code is failing to compile.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

DEFINE_WAIT(mywait);

static int __init test_hello_init(void)
{
    return 0;
}

static void __exit test_hello_exit(void)
{
}

module_init(test_hello_init);
module_exit(test_hello_exit);
```

It fails with the below error, saying initializer element is not constant.

```
In file included from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:21:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:78,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:36,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:19,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/linuxtrainer/Linux_Device_Drivers/day20/3_waitqueue/2/hello.c:2:
./arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:18:17: error: initializer element is not constant
 #define current get_current()
```

Adding DEFINE_WAIT inside test_hello_init works, what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DEFINE_WAIT()` uses an initialiser that is not a compile-time constant - it needs to be executed in process context - so it can't be used at file scope.

It should be used directly in the function that is going to do the wait.